# Uri как отследить FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

Я выбираю из галереи изображение и в последствии его использую как `Uri`, но предположим что пользователь удалил это изображение со своей галереи, как мне узнать о том что `Uri` указывает на фото которого больше не существует?

Comment: new File(uri.getPath()).exists(); - булеан на выходе

Comment: Попробуйте применить этот метод из кода хромиум: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/base/+/master/android/java/src/org/chromium/base/ContentUriUtils.java#99 вроде похоже на то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для моего случая отлично подошел метод

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), uri);
```

В случае отсутствия фотографии метод возвращает `null`

Так же очень хорошим способом является метод предложенный **@woesss**

```
 public static boolean contentUriExists(String uriString) {
        AssetFileDescriptor asf = null;
        try {
            asf = getAssetFileDescriptor(uriString);
            return asf != null;
        } finally {
            // Do not use StreamUtil.closeQuietly here, as AssetFileDescriptor
            // does not implement Closeable until KitKat.
            if (asf != null) {
                try {
                    asf.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // Closing quietly.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Только есть одно **но**! `getBitmap` вычитывает, декодирует и загружает изображение в память, и если вы полученный `Bitmap` не используете - то это лишние расходы. И если таких проверок будет много - это займёт ощутимое время. Во втором варианте тоже есть минус - он проверяет связан ли с `uri` файл-дескриптор, но контент не обязан быть файлом. В случае изображений из галереи это, думаю, будет работать как надо, но с контентом других приложений может не прокатить (если изображения хранятся в базе, например, или отдаются не в файловом потоке)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. В моем случае `Bitmap` используется, поэтому `getBitmap` для меня является хорошим решением, кстати `getBitmap` является `deprecated`, вы знаете метод который актуальный и поддерживается старыми версиями android? @woesss

Answer (score -1):

Создать новый файл с данным путем и проверить на существование с помощью метода `exists()`:

```
File imgFile = new File(uri.getPath());
imgFile.exists(); // true or false
```

Comment: Это прокатит далеко не на любом устройстве. На большинстве галерея выдаст content-uri, который не содержит реальный путь к файлу и такой вариант будет возвращать `false` даже на только что полученный `uri`.